# Getting data from solr with same values and different dates

Tags: solr

I need to get data with a query with SOLR. The query must get me only one doc

I tried grouping and limit the row returned but it doesn't work:

```
select?group.field=dog&group=true&indent=on&q=residential:full AND state:InResidence&rows=1&start=1&wt=xml
```

the docs in SOLR are like this:

```
<doc>
    <dog>Ramon</dog>
    <residential>full</residential>
    <state>InResidence</state>
    <admission>30/04/2019</admission>
</doc>
<doc>
    <dog>Ramon</dog>
    <residential>full</residential>
    <state>InResidence</state>
    <admission>30/08/2019</admission>
</doc>
<doc>
    <dog>Ramon</dog>
    <residential>full</residential>
    <state>out</state>
    <admission>20/04/2018</admission>
</doc>
<doc>
    <dog>Sofia</dog>
    <residential>weekend</residential>
    <state>InResidence</state>
    <admission>30/07/2019</admission>
</doc>
<doc>
    <dog>Albert</dog>
    <residential>full</residential>
    <state>InResidence</state>
    <admission>01/04/2019</admission>
</doc>
```

I need to get any dog withing the type of residential full.
But, in the case of the any dog with the same name, I need the last admitted.
example: if the query get me a Albert, there is no problem. But, if the Query get me Ramon, I need the admitted in 30/08/2019.

There is a possible way to compare dates? or make a better query to get me the data?

Comment: Sorting by the admissions field, as long as you've added it as a proper date field, should work fine.

Comment: I used to sort by admissions field, but, if there is ```solr <doc>
    <dog>Ramon</dog>
    <residential>weekend</residential>
    <state>InResidence</state>
    <admission>30/09/2019</admission>
</doc>
```
Solr sort this doc and get me a trouble

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, add it as a _proper date field_ so it will be sortable, and not just a string.